# Parameter Error on Rails: `param is missing or the value is empty: exercise`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I am trying to access the `exercises#index` page for my app, coming from the `workouts#show` page.  The structure of these models is:

```
  resources :workouts do
    resources :exercises do
      resources :reports, shallow: true
    end
  end
```

I am getting `param is missing or the value is empty: exercise` called on the first line of my parameters.  My entire (UPDATED) `exercises_controller` is:

```
class ExercisesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
      @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:id])
      @exercise = Exercise.new
      @exercises = Exercise.all
  end

  def new
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @exercise = Exercise.new
  end

  def create
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:workout_id])
    exercise = @workout.exercises.build(exercise_params)
    exercise.user = current_user

    if exercise.save
      flash[:notice] = "Results saved successfully."
      redirect_to [@workout]
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Results failed to save."
      redirect_to [@workout]
    end
  end

  def edit
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:id])
    exercise = Exercise.find(params[:id])
    exercise.user = current_user
  end

  def destroy
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:workout_id])
    exercise = @workout.exercises.find(params[:id])

    if exercise.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Exercise was deleted successfully."
      redirect_to [@workout]
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Exercise couldn't be deleted. Try again."
      redirect_to [@workout]
    end
  end

  private

  def exercise_params
      params.require(:exercise).permit(:name, :needs_seconds, :needs_weight, :needs_reps, :workout_id)
  end

  def authorize_user
    exercise = Exercise.find(params[:id])
    unless current_user == current_user.admin?
      flash[:alert] = "You do not have permission to create or delete an exercise."
      redirect_to [exercise.workout]
    end
  end
end
```

The only thing that's all that complicated in my structure is the user will be able to create, edit, and delete `exercises` all from the `exercises#index` page.  The link I'm using to get to this `exercises#index` page is coming from the `workouts#show` page:

```
<%= link_to 'Add/Edit Exercises', workout_exercises_path(@workout, @exercise), method: :index %>
```

Finally, if it's needed here are the applicable routes:

```
   workout_exercise_reports GET    /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/:exercise_id/reports(.:format)     reports#index
                            POST   /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/:exercise_id/reports(.:format)     reports#create
new_workout_exercise_report GET    /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/:exercise_id/reports/new(.:format) reports#new
                edit_report GET    /reports/:id/edit(.:format)                                        reports#edit
                     report GET    /reports/:id(.:format)                                             reports#show
                            PATCH  /reports/:id(.:format)                                             reports#update
                            PUT    /reports/:id(.:format)                                             reports#update
                            DELETE /reports/:id(.:format)                                             reports#destroy
          workout_exercises GET    /workouts/:workout_id/exercises(.:format)                          exercises#index
                            POST   /workouts/:workout_id/exercises(.:format)                          exercises#create
       new_workout_exercise GET    /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/new(.:format)                      exercises#new
      edit_workout_exercise GET    /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/:id/edit(.:format)                 exercises#edit
           workout_exercise GET    /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/:id(.:format)                      exercises#show
                            PATCH  /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/:id(.:format)                      exercises#update
                            PUT    /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/:id(.:format)                      exercises#update
                            DELETE /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/:id(.:format)                      exercises#destroy
                   workouts GET    /workouts(.:format)                                                workouts#index
                            POST   /workouts(.:format)                                                workouts#create
                new_workout GET    /workouts/new(.:format)                                            workouts#new
               edit_workout GET    /workouts/:id/edit(.:format)                                       workouts#edit
                    workout GET    /workouts/:id(.:format)                                            workouts#show
                            PATCH  /workouts/:id(.:format)                                            workouts#update
                            PUT    /workouts/:id(.:format)                                            workouts#update
                            DELETE /workouts/:id(.:format)                                            workouts#destroy
```

Can anyone see what's wrong with my parameters that is generating this error

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Here's my `exercises/index.html.erb`:

```
<div class="container col-sm-10 col-sm-push-1" style="margin-top: 100px">
  <div class="opaque-card md-well well">
    <h1>Current Exercises:</h1>
      <% @exercises.each do |exercise| %>
        <p><%= exercise.name %> (<%= link_to "Delete #{exercise.name}", exercise_path(exercise), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>)</p>
      <% end %>
    <h1>Add New Exercises:</h1>
      <%= render 'exercises/form' %>
  </div> <!-- opaque card -->
</div> <!-- container -->
```

And here's the `exercises/form` it renders:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-push-1">
    <%= form_for @exercise do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :workout_id, value: @workout.id %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :name, class: 'sr-only' %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter exercise name" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        <p><%= f.label :needs_seconds, class: 'sr-only' %>
        <%= f.check_box :needs_seconds, class: 'check_box' %> Report seconds?</p>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        <p><%= f.label :needs_reps, class: 'sr-only' %>
        <%= f.check_box :needs_reps, class: 'check_box' %> Report reps?</p>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        <p><%= f.label :needs_weight, class: 'sr-only' %>
        <%= f.check_box :needs_weight, class: 'check_box' %> Report weight?</p>
      </div>

      <div class="text-center"><%= f.submit "Create Exercise", class: 'btn btn-primary' %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the server log before I hit the error:

```
Started POST "/workouts/d/exercises" for ::1 at 2016-06-03 08:18:26 -0700
Processing by ExercisesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"lygWA3+umw/oGYb/m/W3Oi+M8j/E6+bovZL8zNjO6oZglGkQQkR+FlPNh4CzmQjf4ZE9XffdDLoe4FJ3rPpZ0Q==", "workout_id"=>"d"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Workout Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "workouts".* FROM "workouts" WHERE "workouts"."slug" = ?  ORDER BY "workouts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["slug", "d"]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Comment: Not an answer, but having `method: :index` in the link is not correct.

Comment: Are you sure you posted the same code that is being tested and there's no typo in error text? I.e. `.require(:exercises)` vs `.require(:exercise)`, the error text suggests you're running the former, but in code it's the latter

Comment: @Vasfed, Definitely sure it's `require(:exercise)`.  I copy pasted the controller, but hand typed the error.  I'll fix that above.

Comment: @Pavan, I also tried `method: :show`, which gave me the same error.  What should it be?

Comment: @Liz you do not need any method there - it's `GET` by default

Comment: @Vasfed, so corrected and thank you.  Unfortunately no change on the error though...

Comment: You are confusing with  `action` and  `method`. `method:`  accepts *HTTP* verbs like `get` `post` `put` `patch` etc and the `action:` accepts the actual method names that are defined in the controller i.e, `:index`, `:show`, `:new` etc

Comment: It's not the cause of error. Please show your form view, it seems there's something about it

Comment: Can you show your _form partial?

Comment: The `exercises/index.html.erb` and `exercises/_form.html.erb` have been added above.

Comment: Try changing `<%= form_for @exercise do |f| %>` to `<%= form_for [@workout, @exercise] do |f| %>`

Comment: That didn't change the error, but I think it would have caused another one later on...

Comment: Normally that is how it should be if you have *nested resources*.

Comment: In addition to @Pavan's fix have `@workout` set in `new`/`edit` actions

Comment: @Vasfed Not needed, as the *form* is rendered in the *index* view and index action has `@workout` defined.

Comment: Added definitions for `@workout` in the `new` action and created the following, previously-missing `edit` action:    
`def edit
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:id])
    exercise = Exercise.find(params[:id])
    exercise.user = current_user
  end`  
All good fixes, but none changed the error.

Comment: @Liz Can you update the question with the `params` that are hitting the `create` action.

Comment: I'd assume the error is observed on the `create` action, if so, can you check what the the `exercise_params` method returns or can you paste part of your log that shows the params returned from the browser?

Comment: What does server log show in `Parameters: {...}` on form submit?

Comment: @Pavan, I just updated the entire text of the `exercises_controller`.

Comment: @Vasfed, and added the server log before the error.

Comment: As you can see, the exercises params is not included in the params your controller receives. My guess is you're rendering the wrong form partial. An example of the parameters that should be returned is: `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"lQXLdIW+Wf3ltzJgPMZr6yQLR/VQt3mWdOwJ48S/O/JXTqZzf/SjgDtGS1QYZv5ewEpajQp04hqDel5mXPW0dg==", "exercise"=>{"workout_id"=>"1", "name"=>"", "needs_seconds"=>"0", "needs_reps"=>"0", "needs_weight"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Create Exercise", "workout_id"=>"1"}`

Comment: @oreoluwa, I render it saying `'exercises/form'`. How would it be looking for a different one?  (And/or how can I fix it?)

Comment: Honestly, I don't have the right response, but here's a way I was able to model it: https://gist.github.com/andela-oakinniranye/461752271e436b945ecac3b5fd23d2c7 which seems to be working fine from my end, you should check it out if there's something you may be missing. Note: I commented out some parts which would have caused a problem on my end as I didn't have some models and methods that you used

Comment: @oreoluwa, still trying to piece together why you did what you did in the model.  (Also, I'm assuming any changes in the controller were so you could get it to work workout-less.)

Comment: @oreoluwa, I made the changes you suggested in the model, but got `undefined method 'values' for []:Array`

Comment: Yes you're correct, but you shouldn't have to change anything in your models, I modelled that so it could work with my existing project, that's why you see me overiding some methods. The only major change I made was for the `<%= form_for @exercise, url: workout_exercises_path(1) do |f| %>`

Comment: Ahhh, my mistake.  When I implement this change (but with `@workout` instead of `1`) the error persists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113755/discussion-between-oreoluwa-and-liz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a [chat with Liz](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113755/discussion-between-oreoluwa-and-liz) and it appears that the problem was from the `show_workout` route, where the `method: :index` was added as an argument to the link_to, which resulted in a POST(instead of a GET) request to the workout_exercise_path. The router directed this to the create action, which was resulted in the aforementioned error.
Resolving this required removing the method: :index.

Other little errors and fixes were the usage of the `Workout.friendly.find(params[:id])` within the exercises_controller, however, params[:id] within this context would be the exercises_id not the workout_id.

Then the form_for object ought to have been to [@workout, @exercise]

Finally in the listing of the exercises on the workout_exercises_path, because there is no route as exercise_path(because of the nested resource), an error was observed. The fix was to change this to workout_exercise_path(@workout, exercise)

Comment: Upon further investigation, the delete somehow stopped working.  I thought I might have broken it so I reverted to your version, changed the faulty link, and it still gives `Couldn't find Exercise with 'id'=5 [WHERE "exercises"."workout_id" = ?]`.  Thoughts?